# Order By Rand by Time (HQL)

Tags: nhibernate, random, pagination, hql

I'm developing a web application using asp.net Mvc 2 and NHibernate, and I'm paging data (products in a category) in my page, but this data are random, so, I'm using a HQL statement link this:

```
string hql = "from Product p where p.Category.Id=:IdCategory order by rand()";
```

It's working fine, but when I page, sometimes the same product appears in the first, second, etc... pages because it's order by rand().

Is there any way to make a random order by fixed by period (time internal) ? Or any solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seed the random number generator:

```
order by rand(123)
```

I would suggest using a session-scoped random number as your seed. That way, the page doesn't suddenly re-sort for a single user, but it's still be sorted differently for every user.

Comment: can I use a SessionId ? Or use Random object to get a number and put on Session and use it! well.. i'll try this! Thanks

Comment: You can use the session ID but you need to convert it to a number first (if it's not already): `Integer.parseInt(sessionId, radix)`.

Comment: thanks man, i think that I'll to cache a number by time (1 or 5 minutes) and use it... thats great! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you're *deliberately* randomising the data. If there's no particular order you want them in, why not just order by the primary key?

Comment: Hi Jon, it's a advertisement product page, and I'd like to randomize the records to the users... because if i didn't do that, the same products are on the firts page always!

Comment: In that case you need to provide some stable ordering based on something which stays constant for each user. Do you have a cookie of any kind there?

Comment: Well, I dont have any cookie or session. But I can rand it and put on Session!