# How to get list of 10 random unique objects with Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, select, unique

Does anyone have HQL query on how to get list of 10 random unique objects from the database?

It should be done in database not in application. I'd like to get something that has better performance than my current solution which pretty much makes 10 requests to get the list filed up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm no HQL expert by any means, but in SQL you would do this with

```
select ... order by RANDOM() limit 10
```

So with a bit of googling, I figured out how to do the [limit bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239723/how-do-you-do-a-limit-query-in-hql) and the [random bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915333/order-by-rand-by-time-hql).

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) in your posts.

Answer (score 11):

HQL would be something like:

```
session.createQuery("select o from Object o order by rand()")
   .setMaxResults(10)
   .list()
```

The rand() is passed through to the database so replace this with whatever function your database uses.

Answer (score 0):

Please feel free to comment and post improvements. This is what I got:

```
public List<Item> getRandomTenItems() {

    DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Item.class).addOrder(Order.desc("id"));
    List<Item> idlist = new LinkedList<Item>(getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria, 0, 1));
    long max =  idlist.get(0).getId();

    criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Item.class).addOrder(Order.asc("id"));
    idlist = new LinkedList<Item>(getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria, 0, 1));
    long min =  idlist.get(0).getId();

    List<Item> rtn = new LinkedList<Item>();
    HashSet<Long> ids = new HashSet<Long>();
    int i=0;
    while(i<10) {
        long itemId = RandomUtils.rand(min, max);
        if(ids.contains(itemId)) continue;
        List<Item> list = new LinkedList<Item>(getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedParam(
                "from Item where archived = false and available = true and id = :itemId", "itemId", itemId));
         if(!list.isEmpty()){
            rtn.add(list.get(0));
            ids.add(list.get(0).getId());
            i++;
         }
    }
    return rtn;
}
```